# zend_db query to doctrine 2 querybuilder conversion

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, doctrine

in dbTable i have

```
 ->joinLeft(array('user_roles' => 'user_roles'),
     'user_roles.user_id = users.user_id AND user_roles.project_id = projects.project_id', null)
                            ->joinLeft(array('roles' => 'roles'),
```

and in doctrine query builder i have

-

```
>join('users.userRole','userRole')
        ->leftJoin('userRole.role','role')
        ->where('project.projectId = :project')
```

but i dont know how to add AND condition in left join clause

help me someone

Comment: Try ->where('project.projectId = :project AND < ... >')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need an AND condition strictly in the LEFT JOIN clause, you should use the doctrine `nativeQuery` method.

But this will do the trick no ?

```
->join('users.userRole','userRole')
->leftJoin('userRole.role','role', 'WITH', 'user_roles.user_id = users.user_id')
->where('project.projectId = :project')
```

I guess `User` and `Project` are Doctrine entities so you should use entity definition in your where clauses.

```
->where('project = :project') // where project is an instance of Project
```